# Apache Virtual Host RewriteRule to Index

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use RewriteRule in my Virtual Host to make any request go to index.php. This is what I have in my current .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@site.com
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias www.site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

With this setting I get the following error:

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at site.com Port 80

If I remove the following line:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The site loads.

I have tried the following which have also failed:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^. index.php [L]
RewriteRule . index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php
RewriteRule "^" "index.php" [L]
RewriteRule "." "index.php"
```

and similar combinations

How to I get my VirtualHost to make any request go to index.php?

Also I do not have a .htaccess file and mod_rewrite is enabled.